# Bash while read loop breaking early

Tags: bash, shell

I've been banging my head against for wall for a while with this one.

I want to SSH into a set of machines and check whether they are available (accepting connections and not being used). I have created a small script, tssh, which does just that:

```
#!/bin/bash

host=$1
timeout=${2:-1}

ssh -qo "ConnectTimeout $timeout" $host "[ \`who | cut -f1 | wc -l \` -eq 0 ] && exit 0 || exit 1"
```

This script works correctly. Returning 255 if there was a connection problem, 1 if the machine is busy and 0 if everything is good. If anyone knows a better way to do this please let me know.

So next I try and call tssh on my set of machines using a while read loop, and this is where it all goes wrong. The loop exits as soon as tssh returns 0 and never completes the full set.

```
while read nu ; do tssh "MYBOXES$nu" ; done < <(ruby -e '(0..20).each { |i| puts i }')
```

At first I thought this was a subshell problem but apparently not.
Any help, along with comments on style/content, would be much appreciated!
I know I'm going to kick myself when I find out why...

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Perl's Net::SSH::Perl, @Foo-Bah has described the problem really well, and the solution is to add an empty string as parameter to the cmd:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl#out-err-exit-ssh-cmd-cmd-stdin
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd, "");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if it would help, but a cleaner way of writing that would be

```
for nu in `ruby -e '(0..20).each { |i| puts i}'`; do
  tssh "MYBOXES$nu" 
done
```

Comment: Also, if you have GNU Coreutils, you can use `seq 0 20` instead of the ruby command.

Comment: @Paul

Thanks, that works! Now if I only i knew why!
Maybe it is a subshell issue after all. Certainly reminds of previous subshell issues I've had.

@Jouni

I replaced the ugly ruby part with seq. Wasn't aware of that command, thanks.

@All

Any insight into why this fix works?

Comment: @Paul It's a ssh issue.  I will make a post

Comment: I wish the people downvoting this would explain why.

Comment: The `while..done` loop is also problematic with running ssh inside it. Using a `for` loop instead, usually fixes the problem.

Answer (score 49):

Chris is correct.  The source of the loop breaking was SSH using stdin, however guns is correct in is usage of a looping methodology.

If you are looping through input (a file with a list of hostnames for example), and calling SSH, you need to pass the -n parameter, otherwise your loop based on input will fail.

```
while read host; do
  ssh -n $host "remote command" >> output.txt
done << host_list_file.txt
```

Answer (score 37):

In the construct

```
something | 
while read x; do 
    ssh ...
done
```

the standard input as seen by the while loop is the output of `something`.

The default behavior of `ssh` is to read standard input.  This allows you to do things like

```
cat id_rsa.pub | ssh new_box "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Now, with that being said, when the first value is read, the first ssh command will read the entire input from `something`.  Then, by the time ssh finishes, there is no output left, and `read` stops.

The fix is `ssh -n ...` e.g.

```
cat /etc/hosts | awk '{print $2}' | while read x; do
    ssh -n $x "do_something_on_the_machine"
done
```

Comment: `while read x; do ...; done < <(awk '{print $2}' </etc/hosts)` would be better behaved, avoiding the problems described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 13):

Most of the answers are specific to ssh. Other commands also hijack stdin and do not have a -n option. This should address any other commands. This should also work for ssh.

```
while read x; do 
    # Make sure command does not hijack stdin
    echo "" | command $x
done < /path/to/some/file
```

Comment: That's quite inefficient compared to `command "$x" </dev/null`. `echo "" |` requires a `fork()`, a `mkfifo()`, etc; and it moves `command` out-of-process, so even if it's a shell function, it can't set variables that persist outside the loop.

Comment: This solved my problem. In my case, using `echo "" |` for some reason made me unable to print the result of the command to stdout. Using @CharlesDuffy's `</dev/null` worked.

Comment: Also worked with `sudo` when running a command that eats input. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this today -- rsh and/or ssh can break a while read loop due to it using stdin.  I put a -n into the ssh line which stops it from trying to use stdin and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also unsure about why it fails, but i like `xargs` and `seq`:

```
seq 0 20 | xargs -n1 tssh MYBOXES
```

Answer (score 3):

As Kaii mentioned, it's really overkill to call ruby or seq (which won't work on BSD or OSX machines) just to output a range of numbers. If you're happy with using bash you can:

```
for i in {0..20}; do
    # command
done
```

I believe this should work for bash 2.05b and up.

Answer (score 2):

i cant believe it was the result of 0 that broke your loop, you can test against this by replacing your tssh command in the loop with "/bin/true" which also returns 0.

regarding style i dont understand why a simple looping shell script needs ruby, perl, seq or jot or any other binary that is not on my *BSD.

you can alternatively use the shells builtin for loop construct, which works at least in ksh, bash:

```
for ((i=0; $i<=20; i++)); do
    tssh "MYBOXES$i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

talk about a "robbing Peter to pay Paul" problem.  I'd been struggling for hours to figure out why my ssh was killing my something|while read loop.

Another way to stick with a while read loop and keep your ssh at the same time is to use the "-n" switch to make STDIN on ssh /dev/null.  Works like a charm for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
[...]
something|while read host
   do
      ssh -nx ${host} fiddleAround
   done
```

(I tend to always use the "-x" too to avoid wasting time negotiating X in a tunnel.)