# HandBrakeCLI command break while loop?

Tags: bash, while-loop, command, io-redirection

In a bash script, result of find is

```
/path/to/file1.nrg
/path/to/file2.nrg
/path/to/file3.nrg
```

i have this while loop:

## process preset

```
processpreset ()
{
    x=$1
    # Replace , by -o -iname for file types.
    iname=" -o -iname \*."
    # Find specified files. Eval allow var prst1_in with find.
    eval "find "$fpath" -type f \( -iname \*."${prst_in[x]//,/$iname}" \) -size ${prst_lim_size[x]}" | sort | while read -r i
    do
        titles=$(HandBrakeCLI --input "$i" --scan |& grep -Po '(?<=DVD has )([0-9]+)')
        if (( $titles > 1 )); then
        echo "DVD has $titles title(s)"
        fi
    done
}
```

the script only echo 1 time `File has 8 title(s)` after it stop, when using `titles="8"` the loop echo for all files in folder. Can anyone point me my error please?

EDIT: what work for me, many thanks Anubhava

```
processpreset ()
{
    x=$1
    # Replace , by -o -iname for file types.
    iname=" -o -iname \*."
    # Find specified files. Eval allow var prst1_in with find.
    eval "find "$fpath" -type f \( -iname \*."${prst_in[x]//,/$iname}" \) -size ${prst_lim_size[x]}" | sort | while read -r i
    do

    titles="$(echo ""|HandBrakeCLI --input "$i" --scan |& grep -Po '(?<=DVD has )([0-9]+)')"
    if (( $titles > 1 )); then
      echo "DVD has $titles title(s)"
    fi
    done
}
```

the `echo ""|` fix the problem.

Comment: But your while loop is just reading variable from stdin.

Comment: from HandBrake Manual     Log data is output to Standard Error
    Encode progress information (ETA, Percent Complete, Avg Encoding framerate etc) are output to Standard Output. why redirecting block the loop to continue, don't understand

Comment: I am talking about `while read -r i` Are you just reading `i` from terminal every time loop runs?

Comment: @anubhava i have edited with the full code, did it answer your question ?

Comment: How many lines you get from `ind $imgpath -type f \( -iname \*.iso -o -iname \*.nrg -o -iname \*.img \)" | sort` command?

Comment: it return 2 files, but as soon as is put `titles=$(HandBrakeCLI --input "$i" --scan |& grep -Po '(?<=DVD has )([0-9]+)')` it return only one file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok try this script:

```
while read -r i
do
        echo "i is: $i"
        titles="$(echo ""|HandBrakeCLI --input "$i" --scan | grep -Po '(?<=DVD has )([0-9]+)')"
        if (( titles > 1 )); then
           echo "DVD has $titles title(s)"
        fi
done < <(find "$imgpath" -type f \( -iname \*.iso -o -iname \*.nrg -o -iname \*.img \) | sort)
```

Comment: no unfortunatly it doesn't work, i have added the full function in my first post since it seems to be more complicated than i thought at the beginning. (there is a missing quote before find in your previous post). thanks for your time

Comment: Thoses post seems to relate a similar problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708097/preventing-a-child-process-handbrakecli-from-causing-the-parent-script-to-exit) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708097/preventing-a-child-process-handbrakecli-from-causing-the-parent-script-to-exit)

Comment: Ah corrected that typo but your code appears to be far more complicated than earlier version.

Comment: Have another link about same issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549405/shell-script-while-read-loop-executes-only-once) this is from far over my skill

Comment: Many thanks, with some modification it work as intended, edited my first post. Don't understand how this `echo ""` can help. `(( titles > 1 ))` doesn't work for me, have to use `$titles`