# bash while loop unintentionally ends after true if

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop

is probably a stupid question, but can't see the reason for while abort.

i have a file like this:

```
"id": "00000000000000000",
"visibilitystate": 1,
"profilestate": 8
"somethingelse": "abc",
"id": "99999999999999999",
"againsomethingelse": "cba"
"visibilitystate": 0,
"profilestate": 9
```

one million or more repetitions, number,designation and value can be different between id and id, but id is always different.
my first thought was read in a loop, store the value in a array and later insert into mysql-db.

i try this:

```
set -x
#Data extract array
array=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)

#Control array
array2=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)

while read a; do
    if [[ ${array2[0]} == 1 ]]; then
        awk '/"id":/ { exit 42 }'
        if [[ $? -eq 42 ]]; then
            echo mysql
            array2[0]=0
        fi
    fi
    if [[ ${array2[0]} == 0 ]]; then
        awk '/"id":/ { exit 42 }'
        if [ $? -eq 42 ]; then
            array[0]=`sed -n 's/.*"id":."\(.*\)",.*/\1/p'`
            array2[0]=1
        fi
    fi
done <testf

set +x
```

after read one line, the loop exit, don't understand why.

output:

```
+ array=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
+ array2=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
+ read a
+ [[ 0 == 1 ]]
+ [[ 0 == 0 ]]
+ awk '/"id":/ { exit 42 }'
+ '[' 42 -eq 42 ']'
++ sed -n 's/.*"id":."\(.*\)",.*/\1/p'
+ array[0]=
+ array2[0]=1
+ read a
+ set +x
```

can someone help me?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346445/bash-while-read-loop-breaking-early

Comment: There is missing information: what are the initial values of array and array2 before entering the loop? Also, what do you want to accomplish? (the while is an implementation detail)

Comment: At script begin i create the arrays with 21 values                
`array=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)` same for array2

Comment: @andy, comments do terrible things with formatting, and this is important enough that you should [add it to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12887685/edit) rather than just relying on comments.

Comment: And per @gpoo, please do tell us what you are trying to accomplish.  This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: my target is: get all values from id to id (next id not included) into array, sometimes that are 21 values sometimes fewer, the array have 21 values because its have a 0 for not found values and i can insert it into mysql

Comment: @gpoo,@ghoti  i'm sorry, you are right its not a finished question. i edit the question, add the two arrays and add counter reset after mysql. in the script i have more such if's for this post i have reduced it to the basic problem. maybe i should better use case?

Comment: Still you are explaining how do you want to solve your problem instead of explaining the problem.  My guess is that you want to parse a file to insert the content into a database, but each column value is stored in a row, but those lines are variable. Is the problem something like what I just explained?

Comment: @gpoo i know while read as read line by line, begin at first stop after last. the first line in this test file is id so i get the value for id in array, then according to my understanding the array2 is 0, so i search what for a designation is in this line, on first line its id, i get the value of id in array, running through again, line 2,3,4. line 5 contains next id, so array2 contain 1, search is id contain in the actual line, when line 5 yes, then echo mysql and set array2 to 0. the problem is that according to debug output and test with echo $a the while loop don't read line 2,3,4...

Comment: @gpoo answer on last question, yes exactly.

Comment: @andy: read my answer.  In the first `awk` executed (after `[[ ${array2[0]} == 0 ]];`, `awk` read the content of the whole file.  So, in the next `while` there is nothing else to read.

Comment: @gpoo yes i see it to late, exactly what my problem was. thank you very much! i think awk  and sed use only the actual line from loop read, but when they read the whole file i see the problem. sorry i was a little beside me, now I go to sleep :) many thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 problems in the script. You are using 3 different commands inside the loop that are reading from stdin (`awk` twice and `sed`).

When you use `awk '/"id":/ { exit 42 }'` it reads everything else (the input file).  You probably want to apply that command in `$a`.  That would be something like:

```bash
echo $a | awk '/"id":/ { exit 42 }'
```

The second error is the same, but in the next `if`.

The third error is similar, but in this case when you use `sed`.  You probably want to do something like:

```bash
array[0]=`echo $a | sed -n 's/.*"id":."\(.*\)",.*/\1/p'`
```

By the way, `test` is a reserved word in bash, you should avoid using it as file name (not related with your problem, though).